# Function that return both address and value

Tags: c++

I want to have a single function for it. what is the best way for it? 
Actually I have a scenario that needs both double value and pointer to double value, to create generate another XML data message.

```
double* TransportMessage::getSize_Ptr()
{
   // double m_quotesize; is data member of the class
    return &m_quotesize;
}

double TransportMessage::getSize()
{
   // double m_quotesize; is data member of the class
    return m_quotesize;
}
```

Basically what I am looking for is, someway to just return a value and if needed fetch address out of it. I know reverse is possible and very easy, and currently I am using that way only.

I am aware of the fact that we cannot do 
`double l_dQuote = &getSize();`
so pls don't catch me on this.. :)

Comment: Why not always return a pointer and then you can get the value via the pointer?

Comment: Don't do it. Don't try to return both a `double *`, and the `double` value pointed to by that `double *`. Just don't.

Comment: I see no need to return both a value and its address; you got the address means by dereference you got the value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you just return a reference? Then you can both read and mutate the class state (although this will cause some pain for your future maintainers - a class should be responsible for maintaining its own state, not giving the rest of the world access to it).

```
double& TransportMessage::get_size_ref()
{
   // double m_quotesize; is data member of the class
    return m_quotesize;
}
```

Comment: same result as making `m_quotesize` public.

Comment: @itwasntpete Almost, but not really. Having a wrapper keeps you in partial control - you can for example return a reference to something else or throw an exception if necessary.

Comment: @itwasntpete Not at all. With the method you can add pre-and-post logic (such as logging), count number of times called, create a `const` version that only returns by value, etc.

Comment: i asked something like that before. [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/202879/which-style-of-member-access-is-preferable). and yes, you both are right.

Comment: yes I can do that @MarkB, but can we have any other way using pointer?